# Can I extend the cors to the routers from app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cors

I have two questions:

- Can I use `cors()` once in my `server.js` instead of calling and `use` it in all my router files?
- Can I `require` express once in my `server.js` instead of calling it in all my router files?

My `server.js` now has no problems to handle CORS like below but the `app` also handles the `users` router.

> `server.js` handles requests to `/`

```
const cors = require('cors');
const express = require('express');
const users = require('./routers/users');
const app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.use('/api/v1/user', users); // Register the user router
```

> `routers/users.js` handles requests to `/users`

```
const cors = require('cors'); // Required again
const express = require('express'); // Required again
const router = express.Router();
router.use(cors());
```

If I don't use `router.use(cors())` I will receive an ***CORS*** on the browser when I access `/api/v1/users`

Comment: Register `app.use(cors());` righ after create express application.

Comment: Thats' what I did in `server.js`. Did you mean I don't have to do `router.use(cors())` in other router files then?

Comment: Provide the way you register your router to the express app.

Comment: I use `app.use('/api/v1/user', users)` and this is also updated in my question. Sorry for missing that bit.

Comment: What is the error you got on the browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes you need to use cors() only once for entire application.
2. No you need to `require` `express` in each file if you are segregating your routes in separate files

Folder structure:

```
+ index.js
+ routers
  + users.js
  + server.js
+ controllers
  + user_controller.js
```

How your *index.js* file should look like:

```js
const cors = require('cors');
const express = require('express');
const serverRoutes = require('./routers/server');

const app = express();

// Allow cross origin access.
app.use(cors());

app.use('/', serverRoutes);
```

How your *server.js* file should look like:

```js
const router = require('express').Router();
const userRoutes = require('./users');


router.use('/api/v1/user', userRoutes); // Register the user router

module.exports = router;
```

How your *user.js* file should look like:

```js
const router = require('express').Router();
const userController = require('../controllers/user_controller');

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    userController.list(req, res); // or whatever your code is.
});

module.exports = router;
```